# Magento 2.2.6 : Add custom phtml file after product price in catalog search result page

Tags: magento2, category, frontend

I want to add custom code in my catalog search page. I don't want to override product/list.phml file .

But, Just display my custom code in catalog search result page after product price.
How to add it?

[image]

I have used this plugin code.It's working in only list product. But, when I search that product I can't find content of my custom phtml.

**di.xml :**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendor-module-category-timer" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\CategoryTimer" sortOrder="16"/>
    </type>
```

**CategoryTimer.php :**

```
public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    return "call2";
}
```

Comment: my guess is the data you render in your plugin are not available in search page. I'd need to see the code that works to give a better answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `<virtualType>` [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for that. Try this below code :

Add this code in your `di.xml` file :

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendorName_moduleName_VirtualPlugin"
                type="vendorName\moduleName\Plugin\MyPlugin" />
    </virtualType>
```

And then you need to create this below plugin file :

```
public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    return "call2";
}
```

I hope it will helpful for you..

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to change plugin code.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay. I'm checking and inform you.

Answer (score 2):

Create Magento_CatalogSearch folder under your custom theme

Add Magento_CatalogSearch\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml and put below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.product.addto">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.data.custom" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::custom.phtml" after="catalogsearch.product.addto" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add custom.phtml file with your content/text/code

```
Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/custom.phtml
```

Change Magento_CatalogSearch to YoucPackage_YourModule in case you are trying code in custom module.